# Saving generated random number in variable Haskell

Tags: haskell, random, numbers

I must do the game called Guess the number as homework. 
(player A thinks of some number a B is guessing which number A thought).

I need to implement it the way, that I will give the program just the interval on which player A will think of some number and then B will be guessing by asking if A's number is for example higher than 60, then A say for example Yes, so B is guessing the number that is just higher than 60 and so on...
I need to implement just function guessTheNumber but I HAVE TO USE FUNCTIONS main and randNumber.

I have a problem with saving generated number to some variable, so I could use it later.
Here's the source with error message.

```
import Random

main a b = getStdGen >>= (\gen -> guessTheNumber gen a b)

randNumber :: StdGen -> Int -> Int -> Int
randNumber gen a b = fst (randomR (a, b) gen)

guessTheNumber gen a b = do             
                a <- randNumber gen a b
        putStr("Player A guessed the number: " ++ a)


-- ERROR "1.hs":8 - Type error in generator
-- *** Term           : randNumber gen a b
-- *** Type           : Int
-- *** Does not match : a b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `randNumber` function is pure. Thus, you use `let` to save the return value.

Also, you have to convert the number to string before printing it: use `show`. And don't use parentheses:

```
guessTheNumber gen a b = do             
    let number = randNumber gen a b
    putStr $ "Player A guessed the number: " ++ show number
```